# Run code on complete status of display property of an element

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
document.getElementById('divContainer').style.display = 'none';
document.Form.submit();
```

Where the content is submitted into a popup window. The problem here is that the submit() runs before the display = none is complete. How do I make sure to run the submit() when the "display" is really "none" ?.
Without Jquery, only pure JS please

Comment: Are you sure? Granted, Javascript is asynchronous, changing a display property is extremely fast. How do you know that submit is executing too soon?

Comment: try adding an alert in between, and check it the display state changes!

Comment: None of the changes you make to the DOM become visible until after the code returns to the main event loop. This allows you to make lots of changes without the user seeing all the intermediate steps along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Changes you make to the DOM aren't rendered until your Javascript returns to the main event loop.

What you can do is run the submit asynchronously using `setTimeout`

```
document.getElementById('divContainer').style.display = 'none';
setTimeout(function() { document.Form.submit(); }, 1);
```